# Putting a type in the Read typeclass doesn't work in the REPL

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm defining a type `GosperInteger`, representing the Eisenstein integers in a complex base, and I'd like to enter these numbers in the REPL and do operations on them. So I put the type in the `Read` and `Show` typeclasses. Here's the code (there's also an `Internals` module, see https://github.com/phma/gosperbase to run it):

```
module Data.GosperBase where
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Word
import Data.GosperBase.Internals
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
import Data.Sequence ((><), (<|), (|>), Seq((:<|)), Seq((:|>)))
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

{- This computes complex numbers in base 2.5-√(-3/4), called the Gosper base
   because it is the scale factor from one Gosper island to the next bigger one.
   The digits are cyclotomic:
    2 3
   6 0 1
    4 5
   For layout of all numbers up to 3 digits, see doc/GosperBase.ps .
-}

newtype GosperInteger = GosperInteger (Seq.Seq Word)

chunkDigitsInt :: Seq.Seq Char -> Maybe (Seq.Seq (Seq.Seq Char))
-- ^If the string ends in 'G', reverses the rest of the characters
-- and groups them into chunks of digitsPerLimb.
chunkDigitsInt (as:|>'G') = Just (Seq.reverse (Seq.chunksOf (fromIntegral digitsPerLimb) (Seq.reverse as)))
chunkDigitsInt as = Nothing

parseChunkRjust :: Seq.Seq Char -> Maybe Word
parseChunkRjust Seq.Empty = Just 0
parseChunkRjust (n:<|ns) =
  let ms = parseChunkRjust ns
  in case ms of
    Just num -> if (n >= '0' && n < '7')
           then Just (7 * num + fromIntegral (ord n - ord '0'))
           else Nothing
    Nothing -> Nothing

showLimb :: Word -> Word -> String
showLimb _ 0 = ""
showLimb val ndig = chr (fromIntegral ((val `div` 7 ^ (ndig-1)) `mod` 7) + ord '0') : (showLimb val (ndig-1))

parseRjust :: Seq.Seq Char -> Maybe (Seq.Seq Word)
parseRjust as =
  let ns = chunkDigitsInt as
  in case ns of
    Just chunks -> traverse parseChunkRjust chunks
    Nothing -> Nothing

showRjust' :: Seq.Seq Word -> String
showRjust' Seq.Empty = ""
showRjust' (a:<|as) = (showLimb a digitsPerLimb) ++ (showRjust' as)

showRjust :: Seq.Seq Word -> String
showRjust Seq.Empty = "0"
showRjust (a:<|as) = (showLimb a (snd (msdPosLimb a))) ++ (showRjust' as)

parse1InitTail :: (String, String) -> Maybe (GosperInteger, String)
parse1InitTail (a,b) =
  let aParse = parseRjust (Seq.fromList a)
  in case aParse of
    Just mant -> Just (GosperInteger mant,b)
    Nothing -> Nothing

parseGosperInteger :: String -> [(GosperInteger, String)]
parseGosperInteger str =
  let its = zip (inits str) (tails str) -- TODO stop on invalid char
  in catMaybes (fmap parse1InitTail its)

instance Read GosperInteger where
  readsPrec _ str = parseGosperInteger str

instance Show GosperInteger where
  show (GosperInteger m) = showRjust m ++ "G"

iAdd :: GosperInteger -> GosperInteger -> GosperInteger
iAdd (GosperInteger a) (GosperInteger b) =
  GosperInteger (stripLeading0 (addRjust a b))

iMult :: GosperInteger -> GosperInteger -> GosperInteger
iMult (GosperInteger a) (GosperInteger b) =
  GosperInteger (stripLeading0 (mulMant a b))
```

I'd like to do

```
> 425G * 256301G
16061525G
```

which requires putting `GosperInteger` in the `Num` typeclass, which I haven't done yet.

Showing a number works, and calling `read` on a string works, but reading a number typed into the REPL does not. Why?

```
> read "45G" :: GosperInteger
45G
> 45G

<interactive>:2:3: error: Data constructor not in scope: G
```

Comment: `read` isn't automatically applied at the GHCi prompt. It was never supposed to do that, and it wouldn't work very well anyway, because `read` needs to know the type you want *before* trying to parse the string. For automatically converting any input string you'd want something that inspects the input to see what kind of data it might represent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that in a proper way (you can probably bodge this by writing an odd `Num` instance).

I think a better approach would be to just write that num instance, then you can write:

```
ghci> 425 * 256301 :: GosperInteger
16061525
```

If you don't want to have to write that `:: GosperInteger` signature you can do a few things:

1. Use `ghci> default (GosperInteger, Double)` that will mean it will automatically pick your `GosperInteger` type if there is ambiguity. You can also use this in normal source files.
2. Define a function `g :: GosperInteger -> GosperInteger; g = id` which you can use to disambiguate manually with less syntactic overhead:

   ```
   ghci> g (425 * 256301)
   16061525
   ```

Comment: If I wrote `425 * 256301 :: GosperInteger`, I'd expect GHCI to interpret the numbers as decimal, then output the product in the Gosper base, which would be about 20 digits long, followed by `G`. The `G` indicates Gosper base; even 2 in Gosper base is not `2G`, but `12G`, and (-2) is `65G`. `25G` is sqrt(-3).

Comment: Haskell has no way to write custom base syntax with a suffix like that. I'm saying you can get quite close by just not writing that `G` suffix.

Answer (score 0):

The GHCi repl doesn't simply call `read` on the text that you type in.  Instead, it has a much more complicated parser that separates your text into various tokens.  One type of token is numeric: any integral number you type in will get "read" as an Integer.  Of course, if you type `32` and want it to be an `Int`, not an `Integer`, this would be a problem, so the `Num` type class has a super convenient `fromInteger` function.  With this, an `Integer` token can be converted into any instance of the `Num` class.

But, you want something slightly different: you want the parser to group together the numeric token along with the `G` token and treat them as one unit.  For full support, you'd need to make an extension to the GHC parser, much like how if you type `2e7` into the prompt, you correctly get a floating point number.  This isn't a simple change you can address in your source file or GHCi settings.

---

With all that said, there are some hacks we can play with.  As Noughtmare mentions, "you can probably bodge this by writing an odd `Num` instance", and indeed you can!  Fair warning: you probably don't want to do this, but let's explore it anyway.

The problem is that the parser returned *two* tokens, one that's numeric and the other that's `G`.  Since it's uppercase, that `G` token is being interpreted as a data constructor (your error message pointed that out too: `" Data constructor not in scope: G"`).  The key is to use this to our advantage.
Consider the following:

```hs
data G = G
  deriving Show

instance Num (G -> GosperInteger) where
  fromInteger i G = integerToGosperInteger i
```

Now, assuming you wrote that function `integerToGosperInteger`, this instance would let you type, e.g., `45G` and produce a `GosperInteger` `45G`.  Hurrah!  You can even do `425G * 256301G` and it will work as expected.  Furthermore, if you cleverly *omit* a `fromInteger` definition from your `Num GosperInteger` class, then you'll get a runtime error if you try to simply use a number like `425` *as* as GosperInteger (that is, you'll get an error for implicit coercions that don't have the `G`).

There are some problems.

- If you try this, you'll find that type inference is pretty terrible.  It probably won't work right at the prompt unless you set `default (GosperInteger, Double)`, and you'll probably want to use lots of type annotations in your source files.
- If you leave out the `G`, you'll get terrible type error messages or, even worse, runtime errors.
- You'll get a warning that your `Num` instance for `G -> GosperInteger` is incomplete.  It *is* incomplete, but there's no sensible definitions for anything else.  You could suppress the warning or set all of the missing methods to `error "This isn't how this is supposed to be used"` or something, but it's still a bit of a blemish in the code.

But, if you can deal with the problems and you squint hard enough, it sorta kinda gets you what you want.